# How to combine three queries into one. Is it possible to combine them and write one cursor?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I haven't had many opportunities to write SQL queries other than very basic ones. I now have a requirement that uses three different queries. I am wondering if the three queries can be combined into one query (or a cursor) and make it run better/quicker and more efficient. Since I am new to writing SQL Queries I may not be using recommended standards. Please feel free to comment/correct.

Below are the queries I am working with:

```
--Main Query
Select
           DTL.DetailId
         , HDR.PersonId
         , ODT.OrderNumber
from
           CMPN.Header HDR
           INNER JOIN
                      CMPN.Detail DTL
                      ON
                                 HDR.HeaderId = DTL.HeaderId
           INNER JOIN
                      CMPN.DetailStatus DST
                      ON
                                 DTL.DetailId = DST.DetailId
           INNER JOIN
                      CMPN.OperationalDetail ODT
                      ON
                                 DTL.DetailId = ODT.DetailId
WHERE
           DST.DetailStatusCode              = 'Approved'
           AND DST.ExpirationTimestamp IS NULL
           and HDR.PayGroup                  = 'Group A';

--Query to get createtime
SELECT
       max(CDS.effectiveTimestamp) as createtime
FROM
       DetailStatus CDS
     , Detail       DTL
WHERE
       DTL.DetailId             = CDS.DetailId
       AND CDS.DetailStatusCode = 'Extracted'
;

--If the createtime is not null
SELECT
       sum (CAD.UnitValue)
     , sum (CAD.RateAmount)
     , sum (CAD.adjustmentAmount)
FROM
       AdjustmentDetail CAD
     , Detail           DTL
WHERE
       CAD.DetailId             = :detailId
       AND CAD.createTimestamp >= :createtime
;

--If the createtime stamp is null
SELECT
       sum (CAD.UnitValue)
     , sum (CAD.RateAmount)
     , sum (CAD.adjustmentAmount)
FROM
       AdjustmentDetail CAD
     , Detail           DTL
WHERE
       DTL.DetailId = CAD.DetailId
;
```

Once the results are combined it should fetch the below:

```
DTL.DetailId 
, HDR.PersonId 
, ODT.OrderNumber
, sum (CAD.UnitValue) 
, sum (CAD.RateAmount) 
, sum (CAD.adjustmentAmount)
```

Below is the relationships among the tables

[image]

Comment: the first query returns multiple rows and the other queries return at the max 1 row result. how should the results look after the results are combined?

Comment: Why have you tag [tag:sql-server] and [tag:plsql]? PL\SQL (Procedure Language SQL) is used by Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: I am looking for the below as final result

DTL.DetailId
, HDR.PersonId
, sum (CAD.UnitValue)
, sum (CAD.RateAmount)
, sum (CAD.adjustmentAmount)

Comment: Also, it's 2020, it's way past time you start using the explicit `JOIN` syntax that was introduced **28 years** ago. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Larnu Corrected the tags

Comment: @Larnu I have edited the original post and update the query to use the explicit join syntax

Comment: I told you in your last request that you should tell us what the tables' unique keys are. This is important, if you want correct answers. We must know how exactly how the tables are related.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have added the table relationships

Comment: If only the primary key is unique in the tables, this means: One header can have many details and one detail can have many statuses, many operational details and many adjustment details. That would also mean that you want to show one row per operational detail and show the same adjustment sums repeatedly for all operational details that belong to the same detail. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.