# Explicit join syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am enhancing an old application that is using a query similar to the below. I would like to convert the syntax to start using the explicit JOIN syntax. What would be the 'explicit join syntax' query for the below:

```
Select
       DTL.DetailId
     , HDR.PersonId
from
       CMPN.Header             HDR
     , CMPN.Detail             DTL
     , CMPN.DetailStatus       DST
     , CMPN.AdjustmentsDetails CAD
where
       HDR.HeaderId                      = DTL.HeaderId
       and DTL.DetailId                  = DST.DetailId
       and DTL.DetailId                  = CAD.DetailId
       and DST.DetailStatusCode          = 'Approved'
       and DST.ExpirationTimestamp IS NULL
       and HDR.Group                     = 'Group A'
;
```

Comment: What are the table's unique keys? It seems the tables `Detail` and `DetailStatus` have either a 1:1 relationship (which is a rather rare thing) or there is one row per detail and status code in the status table. Or what else is the table's key? Can the query produce duplicate result rows?

Comment: No further condition on the `CAD` table? I suppose that there can be multiple rows in that table for one `DetailId`? Then the query produces duplicates. Is this intended? Again: Please tell us what the tables' keys are.

Comment: marc_s's query is the direct translation of your original query and produces the same result (including possible duplicates), which mine is not. So, marc_s's answer is the direct answer to your question. You may want to accept it (i.e. click the check mark next to his answer) :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    DTL.DetailId, HDR.PersonId
FROM
    CMPN.Header HDR
INNER JOIN
    CMPN.Detail DTL ON HDR.HeaderId = DTL.HeaderId
INNER JOIN
    CMPN.DetailStatus DST ON DTL.DetailId = DST.DetailId
INNER JOIN
    CMPN.AdjustmentsDetails CAD ON DTL.DetailId = CAD.DetailId
WHERE
    DST.DetailStatusCode = 'Approved'
    AND DST.ExpirationTimestamp IS NULL
    AND HDR.Group = 'Group A';
```

Comment: CAD is another table that has the following relationship with Detail table

AdjustmentDetail  CAD
DTL.DetailId         = CAD.DetailId

Comment: I have a follow-up question. Here is another thread with the details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277235/how-to-combine-three-queries-into-one-is-it-possible-to-combine-them-and-write

Answer (score 1):

You are showing a query with 1980s-style joins and want to change them to explicit joins, which is a good idea. But joins are not the only means to represent relations in a query.

In your case you are selecting data from two tables, but a third table is involved. You only want to select data from the `header` and `detail`, when a certain entry exists in `detailstatus`. When we want to check whether an entry exists, we usually use an `EXISTS` or an `IN` clause. This also puts the third table where it belongs: in the `WHERE` clause, because it represents nothing more than a condition.

Here is how I would write the query:

```
SELECT dtl.detailid, hdr.personid
FROM cmpn.header hdr
JOIN cmpn.detail dtl ON dtl.headerid = hdr.headerid
WHERE hdr.group = 'Group A'
AND dtl.detailid IN
(
  SELECT detailid
  FROM cmpn.detailstatus
  WHERE detailstatuscode = 'Approved'
  AND expirationtimestamp IS NULL
);
```

The reader of this query will see at a glance that it won't produce duplicates, which is not the case with the original query, where the reader must know whether a query detail can have multiple statuses or not. So, while my query looks a tad long-winded, it is still clearer and thus better maintainable than an only-joins query.

BTW: I've removed

```
and DTL.DetailId = CAD.DetailId
```

because there is no table CAD in your query.